# What behaviour does the "Taxonomist" badge encourage?

Tags: discussion, badges, taxonomist-badge

In line with the "badges and other rewards should encourage desirable behaviour", what desirable behaviour does the **Taxonomist** badge encourage?

- **Taxonomist** - Created a tag used by 50 questions

**Update:** I'm not convinced that in itself having hundreds of tags that are infrequently used is actually a good thing.  As an example I'll go through some of the tags with ~50 questions:

- **jqueryui** (x51) - duplictae of **jquery-ui**
- **uml-modeling** (x51) - each of these quesions would be better tagged as **uml** (x414)
- **fast** (x50) - should be tagged with **performance** instead.
- etc...

Once you get down to the more infrequently used tags it starts to become aparant that the vast majority of these tags should probably not be used as it makes it more difficult to find and group questions.

I just wondered if there was something else that I'm missing.

Comment: Um, thinking up good tags?

Comment: If there were tag synonyms or automatic retags, this would be less of a problem...although I don't really see the problem now, I admit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a tag is used in 50 questions, it is likely to be a good tag: People managed to find it when asking their question, and possibly chose that tag over other variations of it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's a bad badge but like **many** others it has a serious problem: it doesn't scale. Getting it on SO is relatively easy (just like getting "Famous Question", "Great Answer", etc), while getting them on let's say Server Fault is much much more difficult.

They should scale based on the activity on the website.. The more Stack Overflow is popular the easier those badges are to get. Next year they will probably be a joke.

50 questions is now not enough **for SO**, imo.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's easy, unless you were on the site back in its infancy. Those tags are not awarded very often these days, and oten to inappropriate questions (e.g. subjective, fun, bounces between open/closed status regularly).

Comment: In fact I didn't say easy, I said relatively easy. It's relative to other less popular websites, such as SF/SU or any stack exchange website. Now I don't want to get into stack exchange which is a completely different platform, but just as an example: mathoverflow is fairly populated and yet **no one** got a gold badge with the exception of legendary and populist; getting a non-scaling badge on such a website is much more difficult than on SO..

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:

```
Create          = New
Used            = Useful
Used >= 50 Qns  = Very Useful
```

Creating something new and very useful should be a desirable behaviour, yea?

Comment: See my edited question - I'm not really making the jump from Used > 50 times ==> Very useful.  Bear in mind that the top tags have been used > 50,000 times.

Comment: @Kragen - perhaps the rep needed to create new tags should be proportional (via some function) with the number of tags already in the system. So no/few tags -> low rep needed, many tags -> high rep needed.